# My javascript click event run on second click but not on first

Tags: c#, jquery

```
function loadToFalloutPopup() {
    $('#fallout-all-modal').modal({
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true
    });
}

$document.on('click', '.all-fallout-btn', loadToFalloutPopup)
});
```

Html:

```
<button type="button" class="all-fallout-btn" data-dismiss="modal">To Fallout</button>
```

JQuery click event fires on second click but not on first. I dont know what is gong on, please help.

Comment: I reformatted to highlight the extra `})` - I'm guessing this is just from copying to question.  But indicates there is more code - perhaps your click handler is initiated from another click handler?

Comment: **$document** should be **$(document)** unless its specified otherwise

Comment: You need to initialize `modal`  plugin once before clicking... you are initializing it on the click.. so for first click it gets initialized.. for second it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadToFalloutPopup() {
    $('#fallout-all-modal').modal({
    backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() { // always write any event on $(document).ready
    $(document).on('click', '.all-fallout-btn', function() { // use click event like this
        loadToFalloutPopup();
    });
})
```

Comment: Sorry, it still not fire on the first click. but it is working after first click.

Comment: I didn't refresh the browser so.

Comment: but if i replace the code with `$('#fallout-all-modal').modal('show');`, it is working on first click

Comment: on second click, you need to first destroy the modal and angain need to show it.

Comment: *`on second click, you need to first destroy the modal and angain need to show it. `*  very bad idea..

Comment: I think problem is `backdrop: true,
    keyboard: true`, but i dont know why

Comment: We need to initialize `.model` in `$(document).ready` and the use show,close methods in loadToFalloutPopup function

Comment: Thanks,i got your ideal

Comment: I dont think backdrop is really a problem ,, checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2061/

Comment: Thanks for the example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).on('click', '.all-fallout-btn', function(){
loadToFalloutPopup()
});

var count=0
function loadToFalloutPopup() {
    count++
    $('#spanCount').text(count);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="all-fallout-btn" data-dismiss="modal">To Fallout</button><br/><span id='spanCount'>0</span>
```